# Drag items from one div to other, with vertical scrolling

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

There's an issue with trying to drag items from one sortable div to another when vertical scrolling is enabled.

The question: **Having two separate column divs, how do we drag from one to the other while allowing vertical scrolling on the columns (not horizontal scrolling), independent of each other?**

The example that does work is as follows (bootstrap enabled to achieve columns):

```
<div class="demo row" style="overflow:auto">
    <ul id="left-col" class="col-xs-6">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="right-col" class="col-xs-6">
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And JS:

```
$("#left-col").sortable({
    cursor: 'move',
    connectWith: '#right-col',
    containment: '.demo'
});

$("#right-col").sortable({
    cursor: 'move',
    connectWith: '#left-col',
    containment: '.demo'
});
```

The problem with this example is that the scrolling is on the container wrapping both columns. If we instead added the `overflow-y:auto` option to the two individual columns, then we get infinite scrolling in the `x` direction as can be seen in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zekedroid/969qwp2n/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out a clean solution is to wrap each column in its own div as follows:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;position:relative">
```

And set the position of the columns to be `static`. Then it works like a charm.

Comment: Hi i having the same issue now. Can you paste your codes here? Thanks !